# Generics in protocols (Generic parameter 'D' could not be inferred)

Tags: ios, swift, generics, moya, viper

**HttpService Generic protocol:**

```
import Foundation
import Moya

protocol HttpService {
  associatedtype T
  associatedtype D

  typealias ResultClosure<D> = (Result<D, Moya.MoyaError>) -> Void
  typealias ActivityClosure = ((_: NetworkActivityChangeType) -> Void)?

  static func request(
    _ target: T,
    completion: @escaping ResultClosure<D>,
    progress: ProgressBlock?,
    activity: ActivityClosure
  ) -> Cancellable
}
```

**MoyaHttpService inheriting HttpService protocol:**

```
final class MoyaHttpService: HttpService {
  typealias D = Decodable
  typealias T = TargetType

  func request<D: Decodable, T: TargetType>(
    _ target: T,
    completion: @escaping ResultClosure<D>,
    progress: ProgressBlock?,
    activity: ActivityClosure
  ) -> Cancellable {

    let provider = MoyaProvider<T>(endpointClosure: { (target: T) -> Endpoint in
      let endpoint = MoyaProvider.defaultEndpointMapping(for: target)
      //Configuration here
      return endpoint
    })

    return provider.request(target, progress: progress) { (result) in
      switch result {
      case .success(let response):
        guard [200, 201].contains(response.statusCode) else {
          completion(.failure(MoyaError.statusCode(response)))
          return
        }
        guard let obj: D = try? JSONDecoder().decode(D.self, from: response.data) else {
          completion(.failure(MoyaError.jsonMapping(response)))
          return
        }
        completion(.success(obj))
      case .failure(let error):
        completion(.failure(error))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**VIPER > Interactor class:**

```
let service=MoyaHttpService()
 service.request(AuthenticationRouter.getLoginData(request: req), completion: {_ in }, progress: nil, activity: nil)
```

How to call **request** function here? I am calling service.request() wrong.

or:

```
service.request<GetLoginDataResponse,AuthenticationRouter>(AuthenticationRouter.getLoginData(request: req), completion: {_ in }, progress: nil, activity: nil)
```

Gives me error: **Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function**

**Generic parameter 'D' could not be inferred**

Comment: You need to explicitly set the resulting type

Comment: @LeoDabus how to achieve this?

Comment: `(result: WhatEver) in`

Comment: So you need to add the type to the calling method

Comment: @LeoDabus service.request<GetLoginDataResponse,AuthenticationRouter>(AuthenticationRouter.getLoginData(request: req), completion: {_ in }, progress: nil, activity: nil)

throws compiling error. Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

Comment: No you need to add the resulting type. BTW You are not showing `getLoginData` declaration.

Comment: I guess the issue is `completion: {_ in }`

Comment: @LeoDabus 
enum AuthenticationRouter {
    case getLoginData(request: GetLoginDataRequest)
}

Comment: @LeoDabus 

service.request<GetLoginDataResponse,AuthenticationRouter>(AuthenticationRouter.getLoginData(request: req)) { result in
            //
        } progress: { progress in
            //
        } activity: { status in
            //
        }

Comment: again you need to explicitly set the resulting type `(result: Result<Whatever, Error>) in` and remove `<GetLoginDataResponse,AuthenticationRouter>`

Comment: I am passing GetLoginDataResponse resulting type to D generic which is bound to  typealias ResultClosure<D>

Comment: Whatever type you need to pass gotta be in the method signature or in the resulting type as I showed. `Result<D, Moya.MoyaError>` D is generic if you don't tell the compiler what you are trying to decode it can NOT infer the resulting type